# Grid, обтекание блоков

Tags: css

Построена сетка из двух колонок, но с разной высотой, к примеру товары в две колонки.
Подскажите, как сделать с помощью свойства `display: grid`, чтобы колонки обтекали друг-друга?
т.е. за ранее не известно, в каком ряду будет разная высота колонки, т.к. товары выводятся циклом с разным содержимым.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и можно ли это сделать без grid?

Comment: можно. Гуглите в сторону `masonry` сеток.

Comment: а с grid как сделать?

Comment: да, masonry подошёл